# Js: Function that Hides Divs According to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, input, checkbox

I have divs ('items') with checkboxes inside each. How can I hide the items that doesn't have the checkboxes with the selected values checked?

```
<div class='item'> <input type='checkbox' value='green' checked></input> <input type='checkbox' value='red'></input> </div>
<div class='item'> <input type='checkbox' value='yellow'></input> <input type='checkbox' value='orange'></input> </div>


function MyFunction () {

const values = ['green', 'red'];
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
items.forEach(items => {
    if (values.every(values => 

        items.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')[0].value.includes(values) // working (only for the first checked checkbox)

        items.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').forEach((cb, i) => // not working
              cb[i].value.includes(values)
        )
        
    ))
    {
        items.style.display = 'block'
    }
    else {
        items.style.display = 'none'
    }
})

}
```

In the example above, only the first item should be shown after firing myFunction(), because it has the value green from values, and it is checked.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: If you hide the checkboxes that aren't checked how will you check them again?

Comment: I want to hide the container (div) if it has checkbox that doesn't have a specified value (green or red) checked.

Comment: Maybe just don't add them to the page? If you're not able to check them it doesn't seem worth adding them to the DOM.

Comment: Also, your HTML seems off. Each color should be in it's own div right? But you have one div class="item" with two checkboxes. So it seems weird that you want to hide the parent div if just one of the color checkboxes is checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class='item'>
        <input type='checkbox' value='green' checked>Green</input>
        <input type='checkbox' value='red'>Red</input>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        <input type='checkbox' value='yellow'>Yellow</input>
        <input type='checkbox' value='orange'>Orange</input>
    </div>

<script>
    function MyFunction () {
        const values = ['green', 'red'];
        let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
        items.forEach(item => {
            if([].slice.call(item.children).filter(a => a.checked).length > 0) {
                item.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                item.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    }
    MyFunction();
</script>
```